# How to use relative path for $ref in Json Schema

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

Say I have a json schema called child.json.

"$ref": "file:child.json" will work

"$ref": "file:./child.json" will work

That is the only two relative path worked for me. I am using the python validator: http://sacharya.com/validating-json-using-python-jsonschema/

The issue I have is: if i have 3 schema: grandpa.json, parent.json, and child.json; grandpa is referring to parent using "$ref": "file:parent.json and parent is referring to child using "$ref": "file:child.json. Then the above relative path does not work no more

Comment: It seems this was addressed in the following github issue: https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/issues/98

Comment: I have read this post. Does that mean I have to specify the absolute path somewhere (maybe inside my schema or inside the validator )???? I cannot just use relative path directly????

Comment: I don't think so. According to the comments in the post is a matter of file loading and ref resolving. One of them even has built a small tool for dereferencing: https://github.com/gazpachoking/jsonref. Have you tried what they suggest in the post?

Comment: @nishant I dont know if this will work..I have read your posts on github and here regarding the same issue. I hope you can help me on this

Answer (score 1):

Building off the [github issue](https://github.com/Julian/jsonschema/issues/98) linked by @jruizaranguren I ended up with the following which works as expected:

```
import os
import json
import jsonschema

schema_dir = os.path.abspath('resources')
with open(os.path.join(schema_dir, 'schema.json')) as file_object:
    schema = json.load(file_object)

# Your data
data = {"sample": "woo!"}

# Note that the second parameter does nothing.
resolver = jsonschema.RefResolver('file://' + schema_dir + '/', None)

# This will find the correct validator and instantiate it using the resolver.
# Requires that your schema contains a line like this: "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#"
jsonschema.validate(data, schema, resolver=resolver)
```

Comment: This is correct, except a missing closing parenthesis for `open` call.